# Modify attribute of element

Tags: javascript, lift

I would like to know if there exists a way to modify the attributes of an element (for example a `select`) using a JsCmd in lift.

Here the working version I have for now, running the javascript string.

```
Run("document.getElementById(\"select_id\").setAttribute(\"width\", \"30px\");")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Div elements don't have a `disabled` attribute, and when an element does take a `disabled` attribute, it doesn't take `true` as a value for it!

Comment: Thanks, I modified the example.

Comment: Are you asking for the lift/scala code that does the same thing as that raw JS string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JqJE library included in Lift which provides a programatic wrapper around JQuery.

The following snippet will create a link that will set the `width` attribute of `#select_id` to `30px` when clicked.

```
"#link *" #> a( () => JqId("select_id") ~> JqAttr("width","30px"), Text("clickme"))
```

This code snippet provides a full example: https://gist.github.com/725432

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a CSS selector in your snippet, like:

```
"#select_id [width]" #> scala.xml.Text("30px")
```

That will modify the attribute `width` on the element with id `select_id` and set it to 30px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I know that but I would prefer a JavaScript command.

Comment: There is the JqJE library that is essentially a wrapper around JQuery. This example might be what you are looking for: https://gist.github.com/725432 It binds on a element id and sets the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example it is exactly what I was looking for. Can you make an answer with this so that I can accept it?