# Remove attribute of HTML element

Tags: javascript, lift

Following this question: [Modify attribute of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917298/modify-attribute-of-element), I would like to know if there is a clean way to remove an attribute in Lift. For now I directly run the javascript command:

```
Run("document.getElementById(\"elem_id\").removeAttribute(\"disabled\", 0);")
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

For example, to edit an attribute, it is possible to use the following command:

```
(JqId("elem_id")~> JqAttr("disabled", "disabled")).cmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a built in removeAttribute option in JqJE, but you should be able to roll your own. If you define something like this:

```
case class RemoveAttr(key: String) extends JsExp with 
  JsMember with JQueryRight with JQueryLeft {

    def toJsCmd = "removeAttr(" + key.encJs + ")"
}
```

and then call like:

```
JqId("elem_id")~> RemoveAttr("disabled")
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it should accomplish what you are looking to do.

You can find the source for JqJE here: https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/js/jquery/JqJsCmds.scala#L168